# Regular Expression pattern-based stemming not working (Python)

Tags: python, regex

I want to write a function to replace the strings using regular expressions. However, it is not doing the needful. Not sure what is wrong.

I am using Python 3.4.3 on Windows 10.

This is the code from the nltk codebook.

```
import re

replacement_patterns = [
    (r'won\'t', 'will not'),
    (r'can\'t', 'cannot'),
    (r'i\'m', 'i am'),
    (r'ain\'t', 'is not'),
    (r'(\w+)\'ll', '\g<1> will'),
    (r'(\w+)n\'t', '\g<1> not'),
    (r'(\w+)\'ve', '\g<1> have'),
    (r'(\w+)\'s', '\g<1> is'),
    (r'(\w+)\'re', '\g<1> are'),
    (r'(\w+)\'d', '\g<1> would')
]

class RegexpReplacer(object):
    def __init__(self, patterns=replacement_patterns):
        self.patterns = [(re.compile(regex), repl) for (regex, repl) in patterns]
        print("init")
        print(self.patterns)

    def replace(self, text):
        print("In replace")
        s = text
        print(self.patterns)
        for (pattern, repl) in self.patterns:
            s = re.sub(pattern, repl, s)
            print(s)
            return s


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("RegEx replacers")
    replacer = RegexpReplacer()
    result = replacer.replace("can't is a contraction")
    print(result)
    result = replacer.replace("I should've done that thing I didn't do")
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an `indent problem` in your `replace` function:

```
class RegexpReplacer(object):

    def replace(self, text):
        print("In replace")
        s = text
        print(self.patterns)
        for (pattern, repl) in self.patterns:
            s = re.sub(pattern, repl, s)
            print(s)
        return s  #here is the problem
```

---

A little advice on your function, remove the `print` lines to make it more clean and sample.

```
class RegexpReplacer(object):

    def replace(self, text):
        for (pattern, repl) in self.patterns:
            text = re.sub(pattern, repl, text)
        return s
```

Comment: Hello Luoluo, The indent was the problem. I had put the prints in for debugging purposes only. Missed the indent issue. Thanks..!!, Bonson

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the accepted answer there is an additional problem with your code: Use of excape sequences in raw strings. For example

```
r'won\'t'
```

is a raw string (r prefix) that won't expand escape sequences, so your string is actually

```
won\'t
```

Use mixed quotes instead instead:

```
r"won't"
```

This error is not biting you now because `\'` has no special meaning and so it is converted to `'` but it will at some other time, for example

```
r'\\'
```

is a string of lenght 2.

Comment: Thanks Thomas..  I have made the change in the code. An additional question- do I need (r"..? Or shall I remove it and use ("won't","will not").

Comment: No, you don't need it (r-strings per se have nothing to do with regular expressions), however more compilicated regular expresions tend to have lots of excapes: `x\dx` (x - some digit - x). In those cases it is easier to use raw strings and not have to worry whether `\d` gets interpreted on string level or on regex level.